# using proxy with online flash games

Tags: proxy, firewall

when I try to play this flash online game "tankionline.com" using our university proxy I get this error "Cannot establish connection (host: 62.152.57.11, ports: 4444,5190,5223,5222,5050)".

In windows I use "Microsoft Firewall Client for ISA Server" to solve this problem.

how can I solve it in ubuntu?

the problem is not from the browser because I have tried different ones and nothing worked.

thanks

Comment: You can't. Your university blocks these ports for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most proxies restrict available ports.. talk to your network admin

Comment: OK, how come I can solve this problem using "Microsoft Firewall Client for ISA Server"?

Comment: By tunneling? Dunno, never used it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc302450.aspx